# Problem 4 part (a) from Stein's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification

> Let $f$ be a **bounded** function on a compact interval $J$, and let $I(c,r)$ denote
>   the open interval centered at $c$ of radius $r>0$. Let $osc(f,c,r)=\sup|f(x)-f(y)|$, where
>   the supremum is taken over all $x,y\in J\cap I(c,r)$, and define the oscillation of $f$
>   at $c$ by $osc(f,c)=\underset{r\rightarrow 0}{\lim}osc(f,c,r)$. Clearly, $f$ is continuous
>   at $c\in J$ if and only if $osc(f,c)=0$.
>
> Prove that for every $\epsilon>0$, the set of points $c$ in $J$ such that $osc(f,c)\geq \epsilon$
>   is compact.

My Proof Attempt:

*Proof.*
Let the assumptions be as above. Define
\begin{equation*}
D_n=\{c\in J: osc(f,c)\geq 1/n\}
\end{equation*}
We will prove that $D_n$ is compact and that $(D_n)_n$ is a decreasing nested sequence
of sets. Since then 
\begin{equation*}
D=\bigcap^{\infty}_{n=1}D_n
\end{equation*}
would be compact, since $D\subset D_n$ implies $D$ is bounded and arbitrary intersections
of closed sets are still closed. Hence, the proof would follow as $D$ is the set of all points
$c$ in $J$ such that $osc(f,c)\geq 1/n$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, which is equivalent to the claim in the
hypothesis.

So fix $n\in \mathbb{N}$. By definition, $D_n\subset J$. Thus, $D_n$ is a bounded set since $J$ is. 
Now we just need
to show that $D_n$ is a closed set. Let $(s_k)_k\subset D_n$ be a convergent sequence
such that $s_k\rightarrow s$. We will prove that $s$ must be in $D_n$. 
We will separate the case of $s\in J^{\circ}$ and $s\in \partial J$.(Where $J^{\circ}$ denotes the interior and $\partial J$ denotes the boundary).

Assume for now that $s$ is in the interior of $J$. Define
\begin{equation*}
\hat{I}(s,r)=J^{\circ}\cap I(s,r)
\end{equation*}
 Fix $r>0$. Because $s_k\rightarrow s, \exists N\in \mathbb{N} $
such that for all $k\geq N$, we have $s_k\in \hat{I}(s,r)$. 
As $\hat{I}(s,r)$ is open, $\exists r'>0$
such that $I(s_k,r')\subset \hat{I}(s,r)$. Then by definition 
\begin{equation*}
osc(f,s,r)\geq osc(f,s_n,r')\geq 1/n
\end{equation*}
As $r$ was arbitrary, this holds for all $r>0$. Hence, $osc(f,s)\geq 1/n.$ This implies that
$s\in D_n$.

Now for the case that $s\in \partial J$. Since $J$ is a compact interval, it is closed and bounded.

Hence, the boundary of $J$, i.e. $\partial J$, is the set $\{\inf J, \sup J\}$ and denote the
infimum and supremum as $\beta$ and $\alpha$, respectively.

Hence, $s=\beta$ or $s=\alpha$.
For any $r>0$ sufficiently small, $J\cap I(s,r)$ is either the half-open interval $[s, s+r]$, or
$[s-r,s]$. As $(s_k)_k$ was defined as a subset of $D_n$ 
and, thus, a subset of $J$, it follows that
for sufficiently large $k$, $s_k$ in either of the intervals such that $s-r<s_k<s$ or
$s<s_k<s+r$.

Hence, $s_k$ is contained in an open set within $J\cap I(s,r)$ and the
conclusion of the former case holds by the same argument. This completes our proof.

---

Any corrections of the proof or comments on style
are very much appreciated. Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative proof:

Since $J$ is compact, it suffices to show that the set of $c\in J$ s.t. $osc(f,c)\ge \epsilon$ is closed.  Let $(c_k)\rightarrow x$ be a sequence of such points converging to $x\in J$.  We want to show that $osc(f,x)\ge \epsilon$.

For any $\delta>0$, choose $c_k$ s.t. $|x-c_k|<\delta/2$.  Since $osc(f,c_k)\ge \epsilon$, we can find points $a,b$ in a ball of radius $\delta/2$ about $c_k$ with $|a - b|$ arbitrarily close to $\epsilon$.  $a$ and $b$ lie within $\delta$ of $x$, so within any neighborhood of $x$ there are points $a,b$ with $|a-b|$ arbitrarily close to $\epsilon$.  Hence $osc(f,x)\ge \epsilon$, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for the neat proof. But may you comment on the proof that I gave? Seeing a slick proof given by someone else is great, but I'd like to know if what I did was correct, and if not why not.

Comment: @JoeManAnalysis Everything except for your first paragraph is sound, but your set $D$ is totally unrelated to what you are trying to prove. In fact, $D = D_1$, since any point $c$ with oscillation $\ge 1$ also has oscillation $\ge 1/n$ for any $n$. In the remainder of your proof, you show that all of your $D_n$ are compact, and this is essentially the argument you want. It's also essentially the same as what I've put in the answer above--i.e. you look at sequences of points in $D_n$ and show that the limit is also in $D_n$. You should do your proof for general $\epsilon$, rather than $1/n$.

Comment: Thank you! I see what you mean here. Can't believe I didn't notice that!